How to send USDT over TON network using React, '@tonconnect/ui-react' and 'ton'?
Sending USDT as per document requirements does not work. https://docs.ton.org/develop/dapps/ton-connect/message-builders#jetton-transfer
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TonConnectButton, useTonWallet, useTonConnectUI } from '@tonconnect/ui-react';
import { beginCell, toNano, Address } from 'ton';

function App() {
  const wallet = useTonWallet();
  const [tonConnectUI] = useTonConnectUI();
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const sendTransaction = async () => {
    try {
      const recipientAddress = Address.parse('UQBtr8pABwBMQfUM6q9TrNA6IJX8xGspFTNPY35tFgwPrZ2z'); 
      const usdtContractAddress = Address.parse('EQCxE6mUtQJKFnGfaROTKOt1lZbDiiX1kCixRv7Nw2Id_sDs');
      const amount = toNano('1'); // Amount in minimal units (e.g., 1 TON)
      const gasFee = toNano('0.05'); // Gas fee (0.1 TON)

      // Create payload for the smart contract (e.g., for transferring)
      const payload = beginCell()
        .storeUint(0xf8a7ea5, 32) // op transfer
        .storeUint(0, 64) // queryId
        .storeCoins(amount) // deposit_amount
        .storeAddress(recipientAddress) // receiver address
        .storeAddress(recipientAddress) // response_address - address to receive extra GD fee
        .storeUint(0, 1)
        .storeCoins(gasFee) // forward_ton_amount
        .storeUint(0, 1)                           // forward_payload:(Either Cell ^Cell)
        .endCell();
      const transaction = {
        validUntil: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 360, // Transaction validity period
        messages: [
          {
            address: usdtContractAddress.toString(), // Contract address in RAW format
            amount: gasFee.toString(), // Gas amount
            payload: payload.toBoc().toString('base64'),
          },
        ],
      };

      // Send transaction via TonConnect UI
      await tonConnectUI.sendTransaction(transaction);
      alert('USDT transaction sent!');
    } catch (e) {
      // Error handling
      setError('Error sending transaction: ' + e.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <TonConnectButton style={{ float: 'right' }} />
      {wallet && <button onClick={sendTransaction}>Send USDT</button>}
      {error && <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

I was developing a mini app with the ability to connect to a Telegram wallet. After connecting, there is an option to click 'send transaction'. The TON coin transaction was sent without problems.
However, I need to send USDT, so I tried to provide the payload variable is described in the documentation. But the 'wallet' app in Telegram gives the error: 'Unable to verify transaction'.
enter image description here
